# Silverlight Sharepoint client api. Upload file

Tags: c#, silverlight, sharepoint-api

I have silverlight application.
Any examples how can i upload file with sharepoint client api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no SharePoint Client OM that allows to upload files as far as I remember.

To upload file you need to do regular HTTP POST to the location you need to have file created.

You can also try to use Copy.CopyIntoItems method of Copy web service (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/copy(office.12).aspx for 2007, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvccopy.aspx for 2010). Note that this web service is designed to copy documents between SharePoint servers and not to create new ones, so may need extra effort tom make it working.